# replace specific word after specific char in java

Tags: java, regex

I have this String

```
String tst = " {"id":$.id, "parent_id":200}";
```

I am trying to extract $.id from this string and replace it by an other word.
For now I tried:

```
tst = tst.replaceAll("(\\$.).", "other_word");
```

But this code is replacing all the rest (like "parent_id"...) by this other word
here is the output:

```
{"id":other_wordd_mag, "parent_id":200}
```

it's replacing only the "i" from "id_mag" any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to be replacing as expected:

```
String tst = " {\"id\":$.id, \"parent_id\":200}";
System.out.println(tst.replaceAll("\\$\\.id", "other_word"));
```

Output:

```
{"id":other_word, "parent_id":200}
```

**Update**
If you need to substitute some variables inside JSON, you can use the following regexp:

```
String tst = "{\"id\":$.id, \"name\":$.name, \"parent_id\":200}";
System.out.println(tst.replaceAll("(\\$\\.\\w+)", "\"other_word\"")); // using shorthand for word characters
```

output:

```
{"id":"other_word", "name":"other_word", "parent_id":200}
```

Or, if you have a map of variables in the form of key-value pairs, you can use this method:

```
static String replaceVars(String src, Map<String, String> vars) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : vars.entrySet()) {
        src = src.replaceAll("(\\$\\." + e.getKey()+ ")", "\"" + e.getValue()+"\"");
    }
    return src;
}
// -----------

String tstDiff = "{\"id\":$.id, \"name\":$.name, \"parent_id\":200}";
System.out.println(replaceVars(tstDiff, Map.of("id", "my_id", "name", "my_name")));
```

output:

```
{"id":"my_id", "name":"my_name", "parent_id":200}
```

Comment: no it's sometimes "$.id" sometimes "$.name" ... its dynamic (changeable)

Answer (score 0):

Working with these types of strings can be a little bit easier if you know what JSON is.
And Java has also a really good library for handling Json strings called [GSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson).
You can use this library and for this specific case use the fromJson method.

But if you want to work with regex and get familiar with Strings:

```
tst.replaceAll("\\$\\.id", "other_word")
```

This should work properly.